# Android options menu layout

Tags: android, layout, cordova, menu, optionmenu

I want to make the menu options with the following display when in press the menu button

```
--------------
- Logout     -
--------------
- Profile    -
--------------
- Password   -
--------------
- Add        -
--------------
```

but the results on the following devices

```
----------------------
- Logout   - Profile -
----------------------
- Password -   add   -
----------------------
```

how to look like the picture at the top, the following source code

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:menuCategory="container"
        android:title="@string/action_logout"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_password"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:menuCategory="container"
        android:title="@string/action_password"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:menuCategory="container"
        android:title="@string/action_profile"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sync"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:menuCategory="container"
        android:title="@string/action_add"/>
</menu>
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.gap.androidgap5;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View; 

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

thk

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the Menu button in your app it is "deprecated".

it is inconvenient , ugly and annoying. (there are lots of articles in the internet that explain that)

instead i recommend for you to use Action Bar.
here is a tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is fairly old, but I thought I should add to user2953680's response if anyone else comes across this question.

I think this is fine distinction that is almost not worth making. The overflow button has indeed replaced the menu button, but you would access it the same way you would the menu button.

If you read Android's documentation, they say use icons in the Action Bar for important actions that relate to the app's current context, whilst everything else, like help items or the settings items should be placed in the overflow menu. So there is still in effect a menu for users.

To exclude the action item from the menu

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

To include the action in the menu

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Now, depending on the Android version, your menu will appear differently to menus on more recent Android versions - took me ages to figure that out. Whether you can alter their layouts, which is what I think was the purpose behind the original question, is something I'm not sure about.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why are you passing these:

```
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:showAsAction="withText"
android:menuCategory="container"
```

check this tutorial:

https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-options-menu-with-examples